# Can't open port 5228 for GCM use

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, windows-firewall

So here goes. I'm trying to implement `GCM` on my `android` app. The `server` part went good enough but as far as the `client`..
The `client` didn't seem to get the messages from the `google server`. I searched the web for this issue and I saw that it might be because `port 5228` is blocked.
So I searched again how to find our whether thats the problem and I found this `command` which is suppose to tell me if the `port` is open or not:

> telnet domain_name port_number

So I ran this command:

> telnet localhost 5228

And sure enough I got this response:

> Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5228: Connect failed

I didn't gave up and I tried to figure out how to open this port and I found `windows` [manuel](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7) for this but still no go and the `telnet` command above brings the same results.
Now I gave up, if someone can assist or at least point to something wrong in what I did so far it would be great.

Comment: Doesn't the GCM server use http? Where did you see it should be using port 5228?

Comment: From the android guide: Note: If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with GCM in order for your Android devices to receive messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169.

Comment: it could possibly just be your router.  you cant hook up your droid and try it that way?

Comment: unfortunately I can only test it on the `emulator` for now, and maybe it is a stupid question but is the command `telnet localhost 5228` going through the router?

Comment: The emulator doesn't have google play services as far as I know so you couldn't test GCM anyways...

Comment: It doesn't by default but you could install it on it which I did